# App crashes when clicking on a button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build custom number picker, and my app crashes every time I click + or - button. I am not getting any errors in MainActivity.java.
Does someone know what could be the case?
Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvHeight;
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button heightMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.height_min);
        Button heightPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.height_plus);
        tvHeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHeight);

        heightPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                tvHeight.setText(counter);

            }
        });

        heightMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter--;
                tvHeight.setText(counter);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the logcat output?

Comment: why have you tagged this to `numberpicker`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
tvHeight.setText(counter);
```

to

```
tvHeight.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Look at the methods

```
public final void setText (int resid)
```

And this

```
public final void setText (CharSequence text)
```

With the first method Android looks for a Resource with the id metioned if not found you get `ResourceNotFoundException`. There is one that takes int which is Resource Id and the other that takes CharacterSequecne

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the [`setText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method which expect a `CharSequence` as argument. So replace

```
tvHeight.setText(counter);
```

with

```
tvHeight.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Currently you're calling `setText(int resid)` which will try to find the String resource id that you defined in your `strings.xml` file.

So I guess your code throws a `ResourceNotFoundException`.